# Lisrel: Goodness-of-fit with FIML and missing data

Tags: missing-data, goodness-of-fit, structural-equation-modeling

When doing a missing-data analysis with FIML in Lisrel, I don't get a lot of goodness-of-fit statistics. I have discovered that you can calculate the fit-indices using the Chi-Square from an independence model.

Now the question is first of all, how do I estimate an independence model in a missing data analysis with FIML in Lisrel (simplis syntax)? Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I've got a feeling that it might not be possible. Can you impute instead?